# HostingProcess.ParkingWindow error in simple app

Tags: c#, winforms

In the `static void Main()` of my winforms app I get the following exception:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.ParkingWindow'
>   to type 'CSVImport.frmImport'."

This happened afte moving some functionality out to a public class.
I build to framework 3.5.

Here is the kicker: When I start the app by stepping with f10, no exception occurs!

edit: If I start the process with a single F10 press and then F5, all is happiness.

Comment: WTF?  If you step in, with F10, and then RUN with F5 it still works?

Comment: Yes, F10, hten F5 works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:
The exception got generated by the initialization code that started an instance of a helper class, passing frmImport.ActiveForm as a parameter.

The above got executed before the frmImport contructor, so frmImport.ActiveForm is null.

I fixed it by moving the assignment for the helper class and the ActiveForm parameter to the Form_Load event.